# Testing BroadcastReceiver with AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, junit, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm trying to test launching alarm with AlarmManager and accepting it with BroadcastReceiver. I've found this [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/2c3bd2c8b7dd410e8e774d1a0d5516c66ea3aaa0/tests/tests/app/src/android/app/cts/AlarmManagerTest.java), and do everything like there. But it works so-so and fires from time to time (like 1 successful test from 20 attempts):

```
@Test public void testOnReceive_defaultAlarm_accepted() throws Exception {

    final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = mQuestions.getAppComponent().getSharedPrefs();

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() + TIME_DELAY_SNOOZE); // time for alarm

    sharedPrefs.edit()
        .putString(mQuestions.getString(R.string.pref_notification_time_key),
            TimePreference.timeToString(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)))
        .apply(); // set test prefs to alarm

    QuestionNotificationUtils.launchDefaultAlarm(mQuestions, sharedPrefs); // launch alarm

    Thread.sleep(TIME_DELAY_SNOOZE + TIME_DELAY); // wait for alarm to be fired

    assertNotNull(mQuestionNotificationReceiver.mRealmWrapper); // check if injected, and HERE IT FAILS

    verify(mQuestionNotificationReceiver.mRealmWrapper, times(1)).getQuestions(); // check if fired with Mockito
}
```

Launch default alarm is wrapper around this func:

```
private static void launchAlarm(Context ctx, SharedPreferences prefs, int id) {
    final AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    final PendingIntent alarmIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, id, QuestionNotificationReceiver.getIntent(ctx, id),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    final String time = prefs.getString(ctx.getString(R.string.pref_notification_time_key),
        ctx.getString(R.string.questions_preference_fragment_default_notification_time));

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, TimePreference.parseHour(time));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, TimePreference.parseMinute(time));

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        alarmIntent);
}
```

Parts of the broadcast receiver:

```
@Inject RealmWrapper mRealmWrapper;

@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ((Questions) context.getApplicationContext()).getQuestionNotificationReceiverComponent()
        .inject(this);

    onPostInjectReceive(context, intent);
}
```

Also here is @Before method:

```
@Before public void setUp() throws Exception {

    mQuestionNotificationReceiver = new QuestionNotificationReceiver();

    mQuestions.registerReceiver(mQuestionNotificationReceiver,
        new IntentFilter(QuestionNotificationReceiver.getAction(mQuestions)));
}
```

Sometimes it works, it shows, that code is almost right, but it's very very flaky. If I start to use custom `RetryRule` to retry test if it's failed, test becomes very long, since Thread.sleep() takes about 10 seconds. How to manage this situation?

Comment: You use both Calendar.HOUR and Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, is it on purpose?

Comment: @joaonlima hm, really, I'll check, thanks!

Comment: @joaonlima unbelievable! Write the answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either Calendar.HOUR or Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, not both